# Error: read ECONNRESET when trying to establish typeorm connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, centos, typeorm

this is my first time posting, so if anyone would like anymore details let me know. 
Basically I have a Node.JS api that uses typeorm to connect to a postgres docker. On my local machine it works fine, I can connect to my docker, even to the docker database on my server. No errors are thrown. But on my server, a centOS, it throws the following error on start up

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Looking around the internet I couldn't find any similar cases.

Comment: That error simply means `There is no connection to db` so check your connection carefully

Comment: I gathered that. What I couldn't understand is why it wasn't working. I'm guessing it was a firewall issue.

Comment: typeorm just a garbage - it doesn't allow setup keepalive properply. Getting ECONNRESET on localhost is annoying